# Retrieving Oracle Password_Verify_Function

Tags: database, oracle, security, oracle11g

I am an IS auditor and I would like to check how we can retrieve the `PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION` assigned to users. I understand the script `utlpwdmg.sql` can be executed to setup the default password resource limits.

If changes were made using `ALTER PROFILE`, the script `utlpwdmg.sql` will not show the latest settings.

Please let me know what SQL commands I can execute to show *what is the `PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION` stored and used in the system*.

Comment: I  don't work for audit for free. What resources did you looked into? What have you tried? Did you get any error?  Do you know http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/ ? Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query to see source code of stored proc:

```
--Source of all password functions.
select *
from dba_source
where owner = 'SYS'
    and name in
    (
        --The name of all password functions in use.
        --See DBA_USERS.PROFILE to determine which user is using which profile.
        select limit
        from dba_profiles
        where resource_name = 'PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION'
            --Yes, this is intentionally the string 'NULL', that's what Oracle uses here.
            and limit <> 'NULL'
    )
order by name, line;
```

Answer (score 0):

To find out what users are using PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION, you need to find out which profiles are using the function and then see which users are assigned that profile.

select profile from dba_profiles where limit = 'PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION';
select username from dba_users where profile = ;